# Can't execute perl script

Tags: fedora, docker

I am not able to execute in Docker container the perl script:

```
[root@11efb25fa64f perl]# ./launch-commands.pl
./launch-commands.pl
bash: ./launch-commands.pl: Operation not supported
```

It is not a case of privileges:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1   31647   38727 1014 Jan 14 23:11 launch-commands.pl
```

I am using Fedora-36 as base image for my container (also I tried out the Fedora 34)

```
head launch-commands.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

When I installed perl package with:

```
dnf install perl
```

Message is different but still, I am not able to execute the perl script:

```
[root@11efb25fa64f perl]# perl ./launch-commands.pl
Can't open perl script "./launch-commands.pl": Operation not supported'
```

Container was created in this way:

```
docker container run -it --name perl fedora:36
```

Image was taken from Docker Hub:
https://hub.docker.com/_/fedora

Image details:

```
docker image ls
fedora       36        0e68c6a5f825   5 weeks ago    165MB
```

Container details:

```
docker container ls -a

 CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED      

    STATUS                            PORTS     NAME
11efb25fa64f   fedora:36      "/bin/bash"              27 minutes ago   Exited (126) About a minute ago perl
```

Does anyone have an idea why I am not able to execute perl script in Docker container with Fedora 34/36?

**UPDATE:**

mount | grep docker

```
fuse-overlayfs on /var/lib/docker/fuse-overlayfs/4ddab38226cf27392d25efd57233577f744299fccd019a934b5af547a4acaf98/merged type fuse.fuse-overlayfs (rw,nodev,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)
nsfs on /run/docker/netns/97ad8526d392 type nsfs (rw)
fuse-overlayfs on /var/lib/docker/fuse-overlayfs/9a513cb4e3d7e2231760cb8b08ed9d514a7712edbea7171fef30f375a9f6077e/merged type fuse.fuse-overlayfs (rw,nodev,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)
nsfs on /run/docker/netns/d5b7cde0e066 type nsfs (rw)
```

Storage driver:

```
[root@dot docker]# docker info | grep Storage
 Storage Driver: fuse-overlayfs
```

Comment: A few things to check. Unlikely, but is `fapolicyd` enabled? Check with `systemctl status fapolicyd`. Is `selinux set to either disabled or permissive? Is the disk mounted as `noexec`? Finally, check with `getfacl` to make sure acl's aren't blocking the execution.

Comment: Can you type a full command? I see and check that one: `systemctl status fapolicyd` but: 
bash: systemctl: command not found. Let me check which package I need and I will install it. This is a Fedora 36 taken from Docker Registry so it is very lightweight (only about 60MB)  that's why I suppose that there might be many packages missing, configurations etc. But preparing it to working Fedora is not as straightforward as I see.

Comment: How did you run the fedora image? (I mean the arguments passed to `docker run ....`). Also where are you running the perl file and what is the content of this one?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, I added it to the post to clarify my issue.

Comment: @sqr I ran a simple hello world program in perl and I did not get any error. What happens if you run the program by using `perl`: `perl ./launch-commands.pl`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, `perl ./launch-commands.pl -> bash: perl: command not found`. As I see those images from Docker Hub are really light, I mean there is a lack of many packages but I understand that this is how it works with containers - we need to prepare them to our own taste.

Comment: @sqr Yes! Indeed various commands are not installed by default in images-containers. In your case you will have to install perl: `dnf intsall perl` and maybe that works. I said *maybe* because I ran `./launch-commands.pl` without installing perl and I got a different message. If that does not work than let me know

Comment: It is weird, can you list all commands which you used starting from "docker pull fedora:34 `. After installing `dnf install perl` I see `Can't open perl script "./install-simics.pl": Operation not supported' which means the container sees my changes but still without the success. It is mine list of commands from scratch with Fedora 34 this time: 'docker pull fedora:34`, `docker image ls | grep 34 -> fedora       34        af70648d87b6   10 months ago   178MB`. Then `docker container run -it --name perl_issue fedora:34`, meanwhile I copy the proxy/perl files to the container (and install perl).

Comment: @sqr I'm not sure what's wrong in your case. What about installing another docker image? Try it, if you have the same error then the problem might be your system. Btw, edit your question to include your issues, not in comments (in comments is hard to read)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, I edited my post based on our conversation. Are you creating container in the same way as in my previous reply?

Comment: @sqr Yes, I tried both fedora containers (fedora 34 and 36) and all worked correctly. Did you change any docker configuration? For example, the storage path for docker images (which by default is `/var/lib/docker`)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, I added that info to the post not to mess up here.

Comment: @sqr as doneal24 pointed out, maybe the container is mounted as `noexec`. So please show the output of `mount` command. And try using another container image (such as Ubuntu, Alpine ) and if you get the same error then maybe the error is in your host system.

Comment: @Paul Becotte or @Mornor, I saw yours reply herehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555145/cannot-directly-execute-script-on-docker-volume so maybe you can provide some input here. I have mounted with `-v` volume tehn copy and `chmod` the script, still the same.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, sure, I pasted to the post ` mount | grep docker` . I do not see any mention about `noexec`. Thanks for your support Edgar.

Comment: @sqr it should be better to use `mount | grep noexec`. Nevertheless I don't believe the problem is that, maybe is a SELinux/AppArmor issue (btw I didn't find any related to "Operation not supported" in docker. You can contact to fedora developer and report this issue in case the problem is related to fedora image and not to your host operating system )

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, okay Edgar, thank you for your all support, really appreciate it. Coming back to your question, yes, all mount | grep noexec records have noexec (proc, sysfs, cgroups2 etc.) Should be change to exec?

Comment: @sqr same in my case, but one of the mounpoints which doesn't have `noexec` is: `overlay on / type overlay ...`. I think it is the same in your case.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, hmm ... interesting, but I do not have an `overlay` here. All of them have `noexec`. I am using the `Storage Driver: fuse-overlayfs` not sure if it matters. Maybe I start from upgrading the Feodra to the latest one, 37. I am not able even to update my storage driver to `overlay2` I suppose because of Fedora.

Comment: Possible as you said the problem is related to `fuse-overlayfs`. You will have (maybe) to report this to Fedora or `fuse-overlayfs` developers. Can you run containers by using `podman` instead of docker